# Running Maven Liquibase-Hibernate diff causes NoSuchMethodError on PrimaryKey.addColumnName

Tags: hibernate, maven, liquibase

I am trying to use the liquibase-hibernate extension to run a diff between my hibernate models and a MySQL database via maven. I have configured the liquibase maven plugin to get its config from a properties file.

I keep getting 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey.addColumnName'

Please see below my pom.xml, local.properties file and console output - all help much appreciated.

Maybe a bug in liquibase-core or the liquibase maven plugin??

Thanks

mcai

## local.properties:

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zzzzzzzz?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
username=root
password=
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
changeLogFile=changeLogFile.xml
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.zzzzzzzz.repository.model?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

## pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Liquibase will read the properties file for its config -->
                <propertyFile>src/main/resources/local.properties</propertyFile>
                <changeLogFile>liquibase.xml</changeLogFile>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Liquibase Hibernate Extention Depends on Core -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate4</artifactId>
                    <version>3.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <!-- Spring as using Hibernate Reference URL for diff -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>.
            <!-- -->
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

## console output of maven command:

```
mvn liquibase:diff         
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building repository 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.0:diff (default-cli) @ repository ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Parsing Liquibase Properties File
[INFO]   File: src/main/resources/local.properties
[INFO]   'hibernate.dialect' in properties file is not being used by this task.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Executing on Database: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zzzzzzzz?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
INFO 04/12/14 16:01: liquibase-hibernate: Reading hibernate configuration hibernate:spring:com.zzzzzzzz.repository.model?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
INFO 04/12/14 16:01: liquibase-hibernate: Found package com.zzzzzzzz.repository.model
INFO 04/12/14 16:01: liquibase-hibernate: Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
INFO 04/12/14 16:01: liquibase-hibernate: Found hibernate.enhanced_idfalse
Dec 04, 2014 4:01:17 PM org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper logPersistenceUnitInformation
INFO: HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
Dec 04, 2014 4:01:17 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.1.Final}
Dec 04, 2014 4:01:17 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Dec 04, 2014 4:01:17 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Dec 04, 2014 4:01:17 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
Dec 04, 2014 4:01:17 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
INFO 04/12/14 16:01: liquibase-hibernate: Using dialect org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
[INFO] Performing Diff on database root@localhost @ jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zzzzzzzz?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true (Default Schema: zzzzzzzz)

Diff Results:
INFO 04/12/14 16:01: liquibase-hibernate: Found table Product
INFO 04/12/14 16:01: liquibase-hibernate: Found table Product
INFO 04/12/14 16:01: liquibase-hibernate: Found column id integer
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.528s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Dec 04 16:01:17 GMT 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 18M/225M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.0:diff (default-cli) on project repository: Execution default-cli of goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.0:diff failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.0:diff: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: liquibase.structure.core.PrimaryKey.addColumnName(ILjava/lang/String;)Lliquibase/structure/core/PrimaryKey;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.3.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin/3.3.0/liquibase-maven-plugin-3.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/ext/liquibase-hibernate4/3.4/liquibase-hibernate4-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.1.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/jboss/spec/javax/transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.4.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.1.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.1.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-envers/4.3.1.Final/hibernate-envers-4.3.1.Final.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.3.0/liquibase-core-3.3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/snakeyaml-1.13.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-core-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/Users/User/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.0.4/plexus-utils-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an API compatibility issue between Liquibase 3.3.0 and Liquibase-Hibernate 3.4. Liquibase-hibernate 3.5 and Liquibase 3.3.1 address the incompatibility and should both be released very soon.

Comment: There still no release of the the 3.5 version for hibernate3. Any chance you might be able to release that version? Otherwise we are stuck with liquibase 3.2.X when using hibernate3.